# Get The Absolute URL path using Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am trying to get the application running url path inside my `StartupAuth.Cs` class but i am always getting default url which is `127.0.0.1` .But I am getting the absolute url when i am using `IowinContext` i am getting the the absoulte url .How Can i use `Iowin` Context Inside my `ConfigureAUth` Method.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{

    string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName, "UserHostName");
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress, "UserHostName");
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "AbsoluteUri");
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "AbsoluteUri");
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString, "OriginalString");
    esignUtility.CreateLog.CreateTextLog(System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName)[1].ToString(), "DNSHostName");
    ApplicationDbContext.HostUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;


    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```